# Singleton Class : session appears not to be valid sometimes in Android Activity

Tags: java, android, class, singleton

I have this class `MainCls`

```
public class MainCls extends Application {
    public static SecSession secSession;
```

now I have created an activity that set its launch mode to singleTop

my problem is that the `secSession` is appears not to be valid sometimes

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
    OnConnectionFailedListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       if (!MainCls.secSession.isSessionValid()) {
    }
```

on `onCreate` of my `MyActivity`, the `isSessionValid` appears not valid. But sometime it works fines, note that I am always login, and every activity i have is working fine. just this `MyActivity` doesn't work well, and it was set to `singleTop`

Answer (score 1):

According to [development guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) a singletop Activity could be instantiated multiple times. Moreover, this is no "real" singleton. Instead you should use [an enum](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.at/2012/07/why-enum-singleton-are-better-in-java.html). I guess your problems is related to one of these or both problems.